# Is the sorting algorithm used by .NET's `Array.Sort()` method a stable algorithm?

Tags: c#, .net

Is the sorting algorithm used by .NET's `Array.Sort()` method a [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Classification) algorithm?

Comment: When does the difference between stable sort and unstable sort matter?  I'm curious.

Comment: @tuinstoel - When you want to preserver the initial ordering of elements. Let's say you have a list of products that is already sorted by some criteria (IE Alphabetically), if you sort by Category using a stable sort the original sorting criteria is preserved inside the groups of products that are of the same category, the products will now be sorted by category and alphabetically.

Comment: This is glaring omission. [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/), [Golang](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Stable) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) all offer stable in-place sort functions.

Comment: Feature request https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4696

Answer (score 76, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc.aspx):

> This implementation performs an unstable sort; that is, if two elements are equal, their order might not be preserved. In contrast, a stable sort preserves the order of elements that are equal.

The sort uses introspective sort. (Quicksort in version 4.0 and earlier of the .NET framework).

If you need a stable sort, you can use [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx).

Comment: Just note to make answer actual. The sorting method has changed between 4.5 and 4.0, from a quick sort to an [introspective sort](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort).

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) is the same article (introspective sort) in English.

Comment: OrderBy is not always a suitable substitute, because it returns a copy rather than sorts in-place.

Answer (score 73):

Adding to [Rasmus Faber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148074/net-is-arraysort-stable-sort#148081)…

Sorting in LINQ, via [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) and [Enumerable.ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx), is a stable sort implementation, which can be used as an alternative to [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx). From [Enumerable.OrderBy documentation over at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx):

> This method performs a stable sort;
>   that is, if the keys of two elements
>   are equal, the order of the elements
>   is preserved. In contrast, an unstable
>   sort does not preserve the order of
>   elements that have the same key.

Also, any unstable sort implementation, like that of `Array.Sort`, can be stabilized by using the position of the elements in the source sequence or array as an additional key to serve as a tie-breaker. Below is one such implementation, as a generic extension method on any single-dimensional array and which turns `Array.Sort` into a stable sort:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class ArrayExtensions {

    public static void StableSort<T>(this T[] values, Comparison<T> comparison) {
        var keys = new KeyValuePair<int, T>[values.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            keys[i] = new KeyValuePair<int, T>(i, values[i]);
        Array.Sort(keys, values, new StabilizingComparer<T>(comparison));
    }

    private sealed class StabilizingComparer<T> : IComparer<KeyValuePair<int, T>> 
    {
        private readonly Comparison<T> _comparison;

        public StabilizingComparer(Comparison<T> comparison) {
            _comparison = comparison;
        }

        public int Compare(KeyValuePair<int, T> x, 
                           KeyValuePair<int, T> y) {
            var result = _comparison(x.Value, y.Value);
            return result != 0 ? result : x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a sample program using `StableSort` from above:

```
static class Program 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        var unsorted = new[] {
            new Person { BirthYear = 1948, Name = "Cat Stevens" },
            new Person { BirthYear = 1955, Name = "Kevin Costner" },
            new Person { BirthYear = 1952, Name = "Vladimir Putin" },
            new Person { BirthYear = 1955, Name = "Bill Gates" },
            new Person { BirthYear = 1948, Name = "Kathy Bates" },
            new Person { BirthYear = 1956, Name = "David Copperfield" },
            new Person { BirthYear = 1948, Name = "Jean Reno" },
        };

        Array.ForEach(unsorted, Console.WriteLine);

        Console.WriteLine();
        var unstable = (Person[]) unsorted.Clone();
        Array.Sort(unstable, (x, y) => x.BirthYear.CompareTo(y.BirthYear));
        Array.ForEach(unstable, Console.WriteLine);

        Console.WriteLine();
        var stable = (Person[]) unsorted.Clone();
        stable.StableSort((x, y) => x.BirthYear.CompareTo(y.BirthYear));
        Array.ForEach(stable, Console.WriteLine);
    }
}

sealed class Person 
{
    public int BirthYear { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format(
            "{{ BirthYear = {0}, Name = {1} }}", 
            BirthYear, Name);
    }
}
```

Below is the output from the sample program above (running on a machine with Windows Vista SP1 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installed):

```
{ BirthYear = 1948, Name = Cat Stevens }
{ BirthYear = 1955, Name = Kevin Costner }
{ BirthYear = 1952, Name = Vladimir Putin }
{ BirthYear = 1955, Name = Bill Gates }
{ BirthYear = 1948, Name = Kathy Bates }
{ BirthYear = 1956, Name = David Copperfield }
{ BirthYear = 1948, Name = Jean Reno }

{ BirthYear = 1948, Name = Jean Reno }
{ BirthYear = 1948, Name = Kathy Bates }
{ BirthYear = 1948, Name = Cat Stevens }
{ BirthYear = 1952, Name = Vladimir Putin }
{ BirthYear = 1955, Name = Bill Gates }
{ BirthYear = 1955, Name = Kevin Costner }
{ BirthYear = 1956, Name = David Copperfield }

{ BirthYear = 1948, Name = Cat Stevens }
{ BirthYear = 1948, Name = Kathy Bates }
{ BirthYear = 1948, Name = Jean Reno }
{ BirthYear = 1952, Name = Vladimir Putin }
{ BirthYear = 1955, Name = Kevin Costner }
{ BirthYear = 1955, Name = Bill Gates }
{ BirthYear = 1956, Name = David Copperfield }
```

Answer (score 20):

As other answers have stated, Array.Sort isn't stable. However, the LINQ OrderBy methods (and OrderByDescending etc) *are* stable, which can be very useful.

Answer (score 4):

No, it [isn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> This method uses the QuickSort algorithm. This implementation performs an unstable sort

Answer (score -3):

**UPDATE:** This code not stabilizing Array.Sort (ensure that the elements are always sorted in the same order):

```
public static class ComparisonExtensions
{
    public static Comparison<T> WithGetHashCode<T>(this Comparison<T> current)
    {
        return (x, y) =>
        {
            var result = current(x, y);
            if (result == 0)
                return x.GetHashCode() - y.GetHashCode();
            return result;
        };
    }
}
```

Use:

```
Comparison<Person> comparison = (x, y) => x.BirthYear.CompareTo(y.BirthYear);
Array.Sort(unstable, comparison.WithGetHashCode());
```

Comment: You clearly dont understand the meaning of a stable sort. It does not matter `Comparison` you use, `Array.Sort` is unstable.

Comment: I don't thinks so. It's stabilized by HashCode, as far as objects has same HashCode sort it is unstable (it dosen't mean the reference equal). So i wrote the alorithm is stablized by HashCode, means as far as objects has differ HashCode it is stable.

Comment: And what happens when I swap 2 'duplicate' elements before sorting? Do you expect the hashcode to suddenly change?

Comment: If you duplicate object, that means has same HashCode.

Comment: "It does not matter Comparison you use" I don't say that Array.Sort will be stable, I also say like @Atif Aziz "any unstable sort implementation, like that of Array.Sort, can be stabilized" using my method, that's all.

Comment: @leppie: you right, my fault. This code ensure that the elements are always sorted in the same order, not stabilizing Array.Sort()