# Is there any builtin stable sort routine and swap function in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, built-in, standard-library, stable-sort

Is there any in-built stable sort routine in .NET?

I know that C++ has an in-built sort routine under "algorithms" `std::sort()`. Likewise, do we have something to use along with C#?

Also, is there any in-built swap function in .NET?

Comment: std::sort is neither in-built into C++ not guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: Inbuilt? When did this become the builtin?

Comment: The stable one in C++ is `std::stable_sort`.

Comment: After seeing how easy it was to find out about .OrderBy, and seeing that you are asking two completely different questions in one here, I have to go with the downvote, sorry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using "C# stable sort" in Google revealed this SO post as top result:

[Is the sorting algorithm used by .NET's `Array.Sort()` method a stable algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148074/is-the-sorting-algorithm-used-by-nets-array-sort-method-a-stable-algorithm)

So the answer is: `Enumerable.OrderBy` is a stable sort function, not built into C#, but part of the .NET framework libraries.

Concerning "Swap": I don't know of any prebuilt generic swap function in the .NET framework, but [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you find an implementation in less than 10 lines of code:

> ```
> static void Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs)
> {
>     T temp;
>     temp = lhs;
>     lhs = rhs;
>     rhs = temp;
> }
> ```

Comment: Seems odd that such a commonly used function isn't already in .NET. At least it's easy to implement, I guess.