# Does List<T>.Sort suffer worst case performance on sorted lists?

Tags: c#, performance, quicksort

According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) `List<T>.Sort` uses the QuickSort algorithm. I've heard that this can exibit worst case performance when called on a pre-sorted list if the pivot is not chosen wisely.

Does the .NET implementation of QuickSort experience worst case behaviour on pre-sorted lists?

In my case I'm writing a method that's going to do some processing on a list. The list needs to be sorted in order for the method to work. In most usage cases the list will be passed already sorted, but it's not impossible that there will be some small changes to the order. I'm wondering whether it's a good idea to re-sort the list on every method call. Clearly though, I am falling into the [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) trap.

Comment: Or perhaps I should randomise the list before sorting it?

Comment: The .NET implementation is not immune to the worst case scenario, because that is just a characteristic of the quicksort algorithm.

Comment: What would lead you think your data is sorted? Or almost sorted? Can you key your decision off those criteria?

Comment: @dlev When the list is built, it will be ordered correctly, but there's nothing to stop another method calling `Add` on it after that.

Comment: @RichardTowers In that case, maybe you *should* stop other methods from ruining the sorted property. You can restrict direct access to the list, and mediate access through a method that maintains the sorted invariant. Then you can skip a "check for sort and then sort" step, since you can be confident in the ordering at all times. It's your list; you have the power!

Comment: @FishBasketGordo I was assuming that the worst case performance is not purely dependant on the algorithm, but also the [implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Implementation_issues). Is that not the case?

Comment: @dlev That's a very good point. I'd happily mark that as the answer.

Comment: @RichardTowers I'm not sure exactly how .NET implements quicksort, but even with a smarter subroutine to choose the pivot, there's still a configuration of elements that will cause O(n^2) performance. Although, it's less likely that you'll come across that configuration (probably).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edit:* I've edited the question.

My question was badly asked I guess. It should really have been:

> Does `List<T>.Sort` suffer worst case performance on sorted lists?

To which the answer appears to be "No".

I did some testing and it seems that sorted lists require fewer comparisons to sort than randomized lists: https://gist.github.com/3749646

```
const int listSize = 1000;
const int sampleSize = 10000;

var sortedList = Enumerable.Range(0,listSize).ToList();
var unsortedList = new List<int>(sortedList);

var sortedCount = 0;
sortedList.Sort((l,r) => {sortedCount++; return l - r;});
//sortedCount.Dump("Sorted");
// Returns: 10519   

var totalUnsortedComparisons = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
{
    var unsortedCount = 0;
    unsortedList.Shuffle();
    unsortedList.Sort((l,r) => {unsortedCount++; return l - r;});
    totalUnsortedComparisons += unsortedCount;
}

//(totalUnsortedComparisons / sampleSize).Dump("Unsorted");
// Returns: 13547
```

Of course, @dlev raises a valid point. I should never have allowed myself to get into a situation where I was not sure whether my list was sorted.

I've switched to using a [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) instead to avoid this issue.

Comment: The problem is that adding to a SortedList is still an O(log n) operation even when you're always adding to the end of the list because your data is already sorted. Adding to a List is an O(1) operation (except for the occasional add when it is already at capacity). If you expect your data to almost always be in order when being added to the list, using a SortedList might cause slowdown.

Answer (score 3):

Choosing the right algorithm is not premature optimization.

When your list is already sorted or nearly so, it makes sense to use a stable sort.  [.NET ships with one, LINQ's `OrderBy` implementation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/148123/103167)  Unfortunately, it will copy your entire list several times, but copying is still O(N), so for a non-trivial list, that will still be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Until you have hard metrics to make comparisons off of, you would be falling into the premature optimization trap.  Run your code in a loop over 1000 times and gather time for execution using the two different methods to see which is faster and whether it makes a difference.